# Insert Multiple row from excel to ORACLE using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert data from excel to ORACLE, but it doesn't work. Who can help me?Thanks all!
Here is my controller code

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

```
            OracleConnection oraclecon = (OracleConnection)db.Database.Connection;

            // create command and set properties  
            OracleCommand cmd = oraclecon.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand;

            oraclecon.Open();

            string[] MA_TB = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            string[] GHICHU = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
               MA_TB[j] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[j]["MA_TB"]);
                GHICHU[j] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[j]["GHICHU"]);
            }

            OracleParameter mA_TB = new OracleParameter();
            mA_TB.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            mA_TB.Value = MA_TB;

            OracleParameter gHICHU = new OracleParameter();
            gHICHU.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            gHICHU.Value = GHICHU;

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CSKH_IMPTEST_07052019 (ma_tb,ghichu) VALUES (:2, :3)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(mA_TB);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(gHICHU);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oraclecon.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please expand on "but it doesn't work" including the exact text of any error messages you see?

Comment: it dosen't insert value in oracle. it insert "system.string" in column database ORACLE

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've assigned the whole string array to the database parameter:

```
        string[] MA_TB = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

        …

        mA_TB.Value = MA_TB;

        …

        cmd.Parameters.Add(mA_TB);
```

Rather than just one of the string values in the array. This means you'll get `System.String[]` inserted as "the string" rather than `"Hello World"` or whatever. This happens because when you call `Convert.ToString(someobject)` all that will happen is internally `someobject.ToString()` is called. In the absence of any overriding method (and a string array won't have any override) the default `ToString()` is called, and all that does is return the name of the type of the object - in this case a string array

Choose one of the array items to be the parameter value:

```
        mA_TB.Value = MA_TB[0];
```

Or if you want all of them e.g. separated by commas, join them into a single string:

```
        mA_TB.Value = String.Join(",", MA_TB);
```

Edit:

Insert all rows from the dt to the database, let's use these things how they're supposed to be used  (setup command and parameters, repeatedly change values of parameters and execute)..

```
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        OracleConnection oraclecon = (OracleConnection)db.Database.Connection;

        // create command and set properties  
        OracleCommand cmd = oraclecon.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CSKH_IMPTEST_07052019 (ma_tb,ghichu) VALUES (:2, :3)";
        OracleParameter mA_TB = new OracleParameter();
        mA_TB.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(mA_TB);

        OracleParameter gHICHU = new OracleParameter();
        gHICHU.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(gHICHU);

        oraclecon.Open();

        foreach(DataRow ro in dt.Rows)
        {
            mA_TB.Value = ro["MA_TB"].ToString();
            gHICHU.Value = ro["GHICHU"].ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        oraclecon.Close();
```

Comment: two of ways  also doesn't work, if i use the way  " mA_TB.Value = String.Join(",", MA_TB); " it inserts 4 rows 'System.String[]' into database

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you have 100 rows in your datatable, do you want 100 rows in your db, or 1 row with 100 comma separated values?

Comment: i want to insert data from excel file to database! for example: in my excel file have 100 rows, i will insert all of them to database

Comment: I made an edit; it might have some minor typo or syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task that I did with Epplus and Entity Framework by looping through the Excel table and creating new objects, and add them to the database.
There are many examples on the internet.

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-and-export-data-using-epplus-core/
- https://www.paragon-inc.com/blog/easy_excel_interaction_pt6

An example with Epplus:

```
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    var users = new List<User>();
    var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(upload.InputStream);
    // Reading the first worksheet
    var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    // Number of rows and columns
    int totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
    int totalCols = expectedHeaders.Count();

    for (int row = 1; row <= totalRows; row++)
    {
        // Filling variables or creating objects
        var Name = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text;
...
    }
...
}
```

Then you can do a foreach through your list where you can add the items to the database.